# CSS selector for first and last element with certain class within a block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the first and last element with a certain class within a block element. The elements I wish to style are not direct descendants of the block:

```
<div id="list">
  <div>
    <p class="line">This is the first line. I want to style this.</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">This is the last line. I want to style this too.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
</div>
```

So in this case, I'm trying to select the first and last lines with class "line" within #list.

Is this at all possible?

**Edit:**

Although all answers below work, I found out I over-simplified the problem. What I want apparently can't be done with CSS and requires at least some javascript. In a nutshell: I have a table with a variable number of rows. Some of these rows are of a certain class. Where these rows are inside the table is variable and can actually change through user interaction. But I need to style a column inside the first and last of the rows of this class. I can add a code-sample but since the answers given actually solve my original question, I think it's best to leave this question as is (and perhaps start a new for the "real" problem).

Comment: Need to target the parent div as well, :first-child, :nth-child(2) ...

Comment: it's static you can, if it's not static you cannot

Answer (score 3):

If the structure is strict enough you can use `:fist-child` and `:last-child`.

```css
#list>div:first-child>.line:first-child,
#list>div:last-child>.line:last-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div>
    <p class="line">This is the first line. I want to style this.</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">This is the last line. I want to style this too.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, with the caveat that you can only target the element using `:first-of-type` or `:last-of-type`.

You *cannot* target the class - there is no `:first-of-class` or `:last-of-class`.

**Working Example:**

```css
#list > div:first-of-type > p:first-of-type,
#list > div:last-of-type > p:last-of-type {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div>
    <p class="line">This is the first line. I want to style this.</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
    <p class="line">This is the last line. I want to style this too.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
  <p class="line">Do not want to style this line</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to add separate class to the first div in the list and the last div in the list. This would make it much simpler to select those elements.

If that is not possible, this would work:

```
#list div:first-child p:first-child {
  color:red;
}
#list div:last-child p:last-child {
  color:red;
}
```